# 中国有的地方都下雪了 some places in China

Tags: translation, grammar

中国有的地方都下雪了

How may translate this sentence, why the translation is “some places are ...”?

中国有的地方都 means “all the places which are in China...”, doesn’t it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

- 中国 - China
- 有的 - some
- 地方 -  places
- 都 - already

(*As an adverb, 都 has many meanings, including: [all; both; without exception; even; already; also; too] In this context  "already" is the most logical choice*)

- 下雪 - snowing
- 了 (final particle - *indicates sentence ends, emphasize the verb, soften tone*)

> "中国有的地方都下雪了"  =  "Some places in China are already snowing"

*It would be less confusing if we use "有些"  instead of "有的". They both mean "some". But "有的" in some context could means "owned" or "have". For example: 我有的是钱 (what I have plenty of, is money); 中国有的是人民 (What China has plenty of, is people)*

To make it even more clear, you can replace "都"  with  "已经" (already)

> "中国有些地方已经下雪了"

Comment: Thanks, I got it !!!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is an over-simplification to say 都 just means already.

In 中国有的地方都下雪了。 都 expresses surprise here, I would translate:

It is snowing in some parts of China, (but not here).

As 高鵬翔 said, the English 'already' is implied.

> ""都" usually come with "已經" => "都已經" = have already "

中国有的地方都已经下雪了。What will you translate now? Now what is 都？？

?? In some parts of China it is already already snowing, (but not here).？？

Answer (score 1):

"[有的](https://www.moedict.tw/%E6%9C%89%E7%9A%84)"地方 = Some places  (should more close using "some of" the places)

The mean you confuse is like this:

"所有"的地方 = "All" the places     .......in china

Or I may use 中國的"有些"地方下雪了

Chinese words have many different mean in different way, just more using would let you remember it.

Comment: "都" usually come with "已經" => "都已經"  = have already ，So if using here will be "中国有的地方都 _已經_ 下雪了"， "Some of places in China have already snowing!"

Comment: Thank you very much!!!